# Django/Postgresql : Is the server running on host "xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql

When I try `python manage.py makemigrations` or `migrate` or `runserver`in django terminal, I am getting this error ;

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused    
      Is the server running on host "my_remote_ip" and accepting
      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'll give you my `settings.py - databases settings`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'my_database_name',
    'USER': 'my_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
    'HOST': 'my_remote_ip',   <-- and also I try localhost
    'PORT': '',               <-- default 5432
}
}
```

this is my `postgresql.conf` settings ;

```
listen_addresses = 'my_remote_ip'
port = 5432
```

also I try

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

and this is my `pg_hba.conf` settings ;

```
#IPv4 local connections:
host   all   all  my_remote_ip/32  md5

#IPv6 local connections:
host   all   all   ::1/128         md5
```

In my remote server, all port is opened by host and there is no problem with firewall.

What is the problem ?.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure postgres is running on your computer.

Comment: 'HOST': 'localhost'',   in Django settings.py solved my problem